# plist not updating in ios project (swift 3.0)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, plist

I need to persist 5 boolean values to keep track of user's progress in the app. I thought using Core Date for this purpose was overkill so I decided to use Property List (PList) instead.

In my app, there is `ToolTipData.plist` where I store 5 boolean values. The default boolean values are false. And I want to change the values to true in certain occasions.

Here is how I update the value in dictionary and write to plist:

```
  static func updatePList() {
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "TooltipViewData", ofType: "plist") {
            let dic = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
            dic?.setValue(NSNumber.init(booleanLiteral: true), forKey: "firstToolTipViewSeen")
            if dic?.write(toFile: path, atomically: true) == true {
                print("saved")
            } else {
                print("not saved")
            }
            print("reading updated plist: \(NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: path))")
        }
    }
```

As a result, I get `saved` prints and

```
reading updated plist: Optional({
    firstToolTipViewSeen = 1;
    secondToolTipViewSeen = 0;
    thirdToolTipViewSeen = 0;
})
```

Then, I click the Plist file in the app then I find that
`firstToolTipViewSeen`'s value is still `NO` even though I updated to `YES` through above method. Is PList file not supposed to be updated or am i doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Files in the app's bundle cannot be written.

You should create the plist in the `Library` directory and then modify from there.

Here's how to create the file:

```
var appDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.LibraryDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
let plistURL = documentDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("TooltipViewData.plist")
do {
    let fileExists = try plistURL.checkResourceIsReachable()
    if !fileExists {
        // create the plist, or move the plist from the main app bundle to plistURL
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

You can then save to the plist like you did before, this time using the URL `plistURL`.

Just a suggestion: Save user's prefences to [`NSUserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults)

Comment: I see. Is plist file saved in the document directory persistable? Meaning, does it last forever even if there's an app update or something else unless I purposely delete it? Lastly, can you give me more info where I in documents directory I should save the file?

Comment: It is persistable

Comment: Oh and actually the library directory should be used

Comment: Why so? Can you tell me the difference between library & document directory?

Comment: Document directory is used to save user created content. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html